# Grails 2.0.3 ignores nullable constraint

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We are having issues with Grails where it ignores the nullable contraint in some cases. For example:

```
class SomeSetting {
    ...
    Employee manager
    ...

    static belongsTo = [ employee: Employee ]

    static constaints = {
        manager nullable: true
    }
}

class Employee {
    ...

    static hasOne = [ settings: SomeSetting ]
}
```

grails keeps on creating the database with the manager field being `NOT NULL` for the `SomeSetting` class. This is just a crude example. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this. We do not want to make the default value `NOT NULL` for fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by using `static mappedBy = [ ... ]`